# Axios No Progress Events when uploading to S3 and app is hosted in S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, axios

I'm using Axios to upload to a S3 bucket.

```
    const response = await axios.put(signedUrl, file, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': contentType},
        cancelToken,
        onUploadProgress: e => progressEvent(e),
        })
```

On localhost I get progress events, when the app is hosted I get no progress events.

It's uploading to a seperate bucket as well from where the app is hosted.